# How to correct RGB color taken with camera?

Tags: c++, image-processing, rgb, photo, cimg

I had this question in my mind lately: I have taken a photo of a picture in my computer's display using my phone's camera (2MP) then transferred the picture to my computer. What i have noticed is that the individual pixel (RGB) values of the photographed image are different from the original picture (which is obvious !) but the color *looks* the same; so what i intend to do is modify the photographed image so that the pixel color values (RGB) are the same as the original (100% if possible), in other words make every pixel identical to the original picture ! without making use of the original picture.

I do not know if this is possible or not but any help will be extremely appreciated, I'm using Visual c++ 2005 with CIMG Library for processing images !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: To do colour correction, you either need to have access to information about the original picture, or you need a mathematical model that describes how the pixel values are affected going from one to the other. If you have neither, you can't do colour correction.

Comment: 1: How do you know what the RGB pixel values were when the picture was on your camera, and 2: if the image looks the same why do you care to change them?

Comment: There is a lot to this process.  You should look up the terms "demosaicing" and "Bayer pattern".

Comment: @jdv:I need to recover the exact values of the original pixels, the image is not too important, but of course it must be the same ! @Reinderin: If you could please elaborate a little more on the mathematical model.

Comment: @xscott: Thanks for the info, i'll see to it !

Comment: Regarding the mathematical model: Between two different images in a camera operation, capture operation or what have you, the characteristics of the system will change the pixel values. This change is expressed as a ramp function. If you don't know the ramp function, you can't work backwards. This leads me to ask the same question that jdv asked: How do you know that the pixel values changed, if you don't have access to the original image?

Answer (score 0):

I'm more interested in WHY you photograph your own screen? If you are running windows you can just press the "Print Screen" key on your keyboard and then open, for example Paint and paste the image.

The colour difference is there because you have not white balanced your camera. Even the most mobile phone cameras can white balance. Take a picture filled entirely with white on your screen. Then tell the camera to use it as a reference for white. Take your photo and it should be correct.